# Short story or novella. Two orphans live in a country ruled by a supervillan. The younger, a boy, hero worships the leader. Has a book all about him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, super-hero

I read this about 5 years ago. It was in a collection of Science Fiction stories.

The two children live alone, in poverty,in a flat in a tower block, since their parents died. They have an old lady neighbour who helps them out. It is a small fictional country ruled by a super villain. The younger sibling is a boy of about ten years old. He has an illustrated book all about the life of their 'great leader.' He hero worships the supervillain.

The elder sibling is a girl of about sixteen. She gets a job on a construction crew. She is working entirety with men older than her, but they all treat her respectfully.

They have a friend who was injured in war. He is now a cyborg. He roasts sausage in his chest cavity and sells them.

Their country is bombed and attacked by soldiers with superpowers. The young boy is seriously injured.

The names of the people in the city sound East European.

I think the name of the story is the same as that of the illustrated book about their 'glorious leader' That book is the boy's most treasured possession.

Comment: The detail about the neighbor who roasts nuts in his chest cavity is very evocative... but I'm not finding it.

Comment: I misremembeed   It was sausages the cyborg was cooking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it.

The Illustrated Biography of Lord Grimm by Daryl Gregory

https://clarkesworldmagazine.com/gregory_07_13_reprint/

> “Power Woman,” Elena said in English. She’d read the Illustrated Biography of Lord Grimm to her little brother dozens of times before he learned to read it himself. The Lord’s most significant adversaries were all listed in the appendix, in multiple languages.

I misremembered the chestnuts it was sausages the cyborg was cooking.

> A block from her apartment she heard Mr. Bojars singing out, “Guh-RATE day for sausa-JEZ! Izza GREAT day for SAW-sages!” The mechaneer veteran was parked at his permanent spot at the corner of Glorious Victory Street and Infinite Progress Avenue, in the shadow of the statue of Grimm Triumphant. He saw her crossing the intersection and shouted, “My beautiful Elena! A fat bratwurst to go with that bread, maybe. Perfect for a celebration!”

Comment: That was an entertaining read. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Aha. If you liked the story I can strongly recommend Daryl Gregory's novels as lightweight but entertaining reading.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots you are most welcome.